# Grunt task to kill a PID based on port number

Tags: gruntjs, protractor, selenium-server

Currently am doing the task of killing the PID that is running on a port (4444, of course the selenium server for my protractor tests). For the rest i.e., starting the selenium server and running my protractor tests i have grunt tasks and they are working like a charm. But, if i do not manually kill the process where my selenium server might have been running because of the previous test run, then my tests would not start as the port is already occupied by previous test run.

What i would ideally want as a solution is a grunt task that will fetch all the processes and then filter out based on the port# 4444, then kill that process. Can someone please help me with this grunt task. Thanks in advance.